# JQuery, Show / hide a div based on dynamic radio buttons aka radio34 etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I'm producing a page dynamically and I have several sets of radio buttons. I need to use the record id in the id tag of the radio buttons. e.g.

```
<input type="radio" name="review_flag1797" id="review_flag1797" 
      value="n" checked="checked" />
```

How can I produce a single JQuery function to handle showing / hiding of my div. My radio buttons will have three values `y`, `n` and `r`. When the value is `n` I need to hide my div and show it for `y` and `r`.

To further complicate this, the radio of the radio button can set to a different value when its written.

EDIT

```
<div id="my_content1797">
content
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Which div are you talking about? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? *edit:* And you have several buttons controlling one div?

Comment: @FelixKling It will be a div specific to the set of radio buttons, my problem is finding the div from the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a `data-*` attribute to store the ID of the set, just to make life a bit easier, maybe also give those radio buttons a common class:

```
<input ... class="someClass" ... data-id="1797" ... />
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
$('.someClass').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#my_content' + $(this).data('id')).toggle(this.value !== 'n');
    }
});
```

Comment: So both the inputs and the div need to have the same class set ?

Comment: No, you are only binding the event handler to the input elements. The corresponding div is found through the ID. The class is only added to make selecting the elements easier.

Comment: Cool, looking good, what about having it hidden when the page loads if value is `n` ? I have `style="display:none;"` at the moment :(

Comment: You can just trigger the change event manually `$('.someClass').change()`. But there is nothing wrong with using CSS for this (unless you want the divs be visible if JS is disabled).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the jQuery toggle() method.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
onclick="$('#my_content<%=record_id%>').toggle(this.checked);"
```

Comment: Will this work with dynamically created divs and radio button ids?

Comment: It's better if know the ID of the div you're trying to show/hide, but if it's a child of something (and the only div child), you can select by tag name within the parent. My point is, you need to get a reference to the DIV object at some point. But, yes, dynamic controls are fair game.

Comment: I guess I can dynamically pass the div name into the jquery onclick, but how would that look ?

Comment: Also how which each call differ, as some selction will need the div to remain in the current visible state.

Comment: It really depends on how your dynamic controls are created, and you didn't supply enough source to determine a good way to do this. Are the controls created server side or client side? How many controls are there? What's the general page layout after all the controls are created? How are the IDs generated?

Comment: Ahh.. I see.. When you generate the dynamic controls, you need to generate the "onclick" method dynamically as well passing in "my_content"+control_num for the target.

Comment: I'm using classic ASP. The control are created server side. There could be 10 sets of radios / div, I guess. The ID's are created like this `id="review_flag<%=record_id%>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the parent div using this statement

```
 $("input[value='n']").parent().hide();
```

To show, give

```
 $("input[value!='n']").parent().show();
```

You have to give this after the statements that add radio buttons dynamically, and also in the change handler of radio inputs. You can put these statements in a function and invoke it.

Also try http://api.jquery.com/closest/ if the div is not parent. This also selects parent.

```
 $("input[value='n']").closest(...).hide();
```